# Why doesn't disk io occur to read file system metadata despite clearing dentry and inode with drop_cache command?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, ext4

As the title says, I am confused about "echo # > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" and blockdev --flushbufs.

> http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/file-implementation.pdf

According to OSSTEP, If the target inodes are not cached in memory, disk IO should be occur to read the inode, which will make a dentry data structure on memory.

To my knowledge, echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches is to drop(clear) page cahche, inodes and dentry.

I have experimented with `blktrace` to figure out whether disk io is really occurring to read the inode.

1) `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

```
> 259,0   38        1     0.000000000 40641  Q   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
> 259,0   38        2     0.000004096 40641  G   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
> 259,0   38        3     0.000027108 40641 UT   N [cat] 1
> 259,0   38        4     0.000027862 40641  I   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
> 259,0   38        5     0.000036393 40641  D   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
> 259,0   38        6     0.006268251     0  C   R 109314048 + 32 [0]
```

However, there is no disk io to read inode. I can only see the disk io to read 16KB data block.

2) `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/nvme0n1`

```
259,0    1        1     0.000000000   325  Q  RM 74232 + 8 [cat]     
259,0    1        2     0.000004854   325  G  RM 74232 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1        3     0.000026263   325  D  RM 74232 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1        4     0.006292470     0  C  RM 74232 + 8 [0]
259,0    1        5     0.006382162   325  Q  RM 109052160 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1        6     0.006385621   325  G  RM 109052160 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1        7     0.006393322   325  D  RM 109052160 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1        8     0.006455750     0  C  RM 109052160 + 8 [0]
259,0    1        9     0.006511245   325  Q  RM 109117696 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1       10     0.006512342   325  G  RM 109117696 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1       11     0.006514627   325  D  RM 109117696 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1       12     0.006591933     0  C  RM 109117696 + 8 [0]
259,0    1       13     0.006624544   325  Q  RM 109117704 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1       14     0.006625538   325  G  RM 109117704 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1       15     0.006627567   325  D  RM 109117704 + 8 [cat]
259,0    1       16     0.006688973     0  C  RM 109117704 + 8 [0]
259,0    1       17     0.006764838   325  Q   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
259,0    1       18     0.006766035   325  G   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
259,0    1       19     0.006768078   325 UT   N [cat] 1
259,0    1       20     0.006768755   325  I   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
259,0    1       21     0.006773426   325  D   R 109314048 + 32 [cat]
259,0    1       22     0.006854480     0  C   R 109314048 + 32 [0]
```

I found block access (+8(512*8=4KB)) to read inode.

A quick look at how blockdev --flushbufs works in the kernel code shows that it clears the superblock.

Why doesn't disk io to read inodes with drop_cache alone?

The ULK book says that inodes or superblocks are cached in buffer-cache.
The book ULK says that inodes and superblocks are cached in buffer-cache.
Is this the reason for this?

Thank you